# Restangular flattening models on post?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Say I have the following form comprising a model and a nested model:

```
<label>Company Name</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="company.name" />

<label>Owner Name</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="company.owner.name" />
```

Which I post like this:

```
Restangular.all('companies').post($scope.company);
```

What I'm expecting on the server end (in this case Rails) is a nested hash something like this:

```
company:
    name: Test Company
    owner:
        name: Test Owner
```

But what I'm getting is this:

```
name: Test Company
company:
    name: Test Company
owner:
    name: Test Owner
```

It appears that the models are being flattened, and also the fields from the first model are repeated outside of the scoping.

How can I post the model whilst maintaining its nesting and preferably not repeating the models fields outside of its scope in the hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of Restangular.

Could you `console.log` the output of $scope.company?

Restangular isn't flattering anything. It's just sending the exact JSon that you've provided as a parameter, that's why you should check what is the output of $scope.company.

After that, we can check it further.

Also, have you checked the network tab for the Payload of the request? Is it OK?

Comment: This would be far better suited as a comment, but not an answer to the actual problem.  Debugging is vital, but debugging steps alone don't constitute a solution.

Comment: Agreed. Sorry. Next time I'll comment this instead of adding an answer!

Comment: @mgonto: You're absolutely correct. I wasn't aware that I could check the payload from Restangular, this is the value being sent: "postData": { "mimeType": "application/json;charset=UTF-8", "text": "{\"name\":\"My Company Ltd\",\"owner\":{\"name\":\"Mr Smith\"}}"

Comment: And this is how Rails is receiving it: {"name"=>"My Company Ltd", "owner"=>{"name"=>"Mr Smith"}, "company"=>{"name"=>"My Company Ltd", "owner"=>{"name"=>"Mr Smith"}}} - I don't know why its making a mess of that but the nesting is correct on the company value, so I believe the error was in my Rails controller code :/ Many Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok Rails was previously inferring the "company" scoping from the controller. If I turn off wrap_parameters it removes a lot of the mess and I'm left with this: {"name"=>"My Company Ltd", "owner"=>{"name"=>"Mr Smith"} - Is there a way to make Restangular include a root level element name with the post json?

Comment: You should set requestInterceptor and create there a new object which will have the properties inside the root name. https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/109

Comment: @Makoto I have updated your answer from your comments as this may useful to future visitor of question. As they may not visit comment of yours. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the need to clarify this for anyone else finding this question.

Passing `$scope.company` passes the JS object that is `company` that does not include the name of the scope variable itself:

```
{
    name: 'Test Company',
    owner: {
        name: 'Test Owner'
    }
}
```

The server will see this as a POST variable named `name` that is a string with value 'Test Company' and another variable named `owner` that is an array with an index named `name` with value of 'Test Owner`

In PHP it would be this:

```
$_POST['name']; // would = 'Test Company'
$_POST['owner']; // would = array('name'=>'Test Owner')
```

If you want it to be an array of properties on the server side referred to as `company` then you need to encapsulate `$scope.company` in a JS object itself with a property titled "company":

```
$scope.company = {
     company: {
         name : 'Test Company',
         owner : {
             name : 'Test Owner'
         }
     }
};
```

Now on the server side you'll find this:

```
$_POST['company']; // would = array('name'=>'Test Company','owner'=>array('name'=>'Test Owner'))
```